# How to Return Exception from Function in class

Tags: c#, exception

I am creating a function `createFolding` in my class named `clsFolding`. I am inserting some values in database through this function `createFolding`. So, I am returning `int status_id` from function back (1 if ok, 0 if error). I also want to return an exception message from function if there is error (if `status_id =0`) but I do not know how to return multiple values from my function back. here is my code that I have done in my class `clsFolding`

```cs
public class clsFolding
{
    public static string ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FazalConstructions.Properties.Settings.ConnString"].ConnectionString;
    public static SqlConnection con;
    public static SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    public static int status_id;
    public static Exception ex;

    public static int createFolding(int id, string name, int qty, string narration, DateTime dt)
    {
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblFolding(FoldingID, Name,Quantity,Narration,DateTime)VALUES(@id, @name, @qty, @narration,@dt)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", qty);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@narration", narration);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dt);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            status_id = 1;
            return status_id;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            status_id = 0;
           return status_id;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

here is my code that I used in my form to get data from class

```cs
clsStockManagement.updateStock(
    int.Parse(TransactionID.Text), int.Parse(projectID.Text),
    int.Parse(cbItem.SelectedValue.ToString()),
    int.Parse(tbQty.Text), DateTimee.Value);
if (clsStockManagement.status_id==1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Process Successful", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
else if (clsStockManagement.status_id==0)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Process UnSuccessful", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); 
}
```

Comment: don't return exceptions, throw them

Comment: One popular approach to this is the one adopted by Microsoft for parsing numbers. e.g int.TryParse(text, out number)

Comment: i dont want to throw exception as i want messagebox to show error message to user

Comment: @izcd can you please explain?

Comment: It's fine to show a MessageBox. That sounds like a good idea. But you don't have to check a status code to do it. Throw the exception, have a try/catch block in the code that calls your method, and _show the message box from the catch block_. In fact, don't even have a try/catch block or any return values in your `createFolding()` method at all. It should be a `void` method that you assume succeeds until the exception handler fires _in the code that calls this method_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're missing the point of exceptions. You rarely catch them where they're thrown. The point of exceptions is to let them bubble up. Done **right**, your `createFolding()` method doesn't need *any* exception handling *or* return codes. It simplifies down to this:

```
public class clsFolding
{
    //no need for this to be public
    private static string ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FazalConstructions.Properties.Settings.ConnString"].ConnectionString;

    public static void createFolding(int id, string name, int qty, string narration, DateTime dt)
    {
         string sql = "INSERT INTO tblFolding(FoldingID, Name,Quantity,Narration,DateTime)VALUES(@id, @name, @qty, @narration,@dt)";

         //fyi: a static SqlConnection reference is a VERY BAD IDEA
         // use a new variable in each method call
         using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
         using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", qty);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@narration", narration);
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dt);

             con.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
    }
}
```

[*I'd also do something about those AddWithValue() calls.*](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Now you want to show a MessageBox if this fails. That's fine. Do that. It sounds like a good idea. Just *do it in the code that calls this method:*

```
try 
{
   clsFolding.createFolding( /* parameters here */);
   MessageBox.Show("Process Successful", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch (SqlException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Process UnSuccessful, could not write to database", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); 
}
catch (Exception Ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Process UnSuccessful, a non-database error occured", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a Model (basically a class with property) which should have an integer and an exception property.

```
public class MyResult{
    public int Status {get; set;}
    public Exception Exception {get; set;}
}
```

Now you can return this class from your function like this,

```
public static MyResult createFolding(int id, string name, int qty, string narration, DateTime dt)
{
    var result = new MyResult();
    try
    {
        // your code
        result.Status = 1;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        result.Status = 0;
        result.Exception = e;
    }
    return result;
}
```

So you are expecting `MyResult` from the function `createFolding`.

In your code where we call this function should be like this,

```
var result = clsFoldingObj.createFolding(1,'abhi',1,'empty', new Date());
if(result.Status == 0){
    // result has an exception
    MessageBox.Show("Process Unsuccessful - "result.Exception.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); 
}
else{
    // Success 
    MessageBox.Show("Process Successful", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Comment: While this will work, it's not really a good solution to the OP's real problem.

Comment: can you please tell me how can i get that exception back in my form as error message. i am getting error that object reference not set to an instance of object.

Comment: @WaqasAli, see the updated answer. Please feel free to ask any doubt on this

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above, it is best practice to throw exceptions rather than returning them. To do this, change the catch part of you sample to the following:

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // You can log the exception here if you need to.
           throw;
        }
```

But: to answer your question about how to return multiple values, create a new class, instantiate it with the result values and return that.

The class will have 2 properties:

```
public class TClass
{
  public int Result { get;set;}
  public Exception Error { get;set;}
}
```

Your sample code will then look as follows:

```
public static int createFolding(int id, string name, int qty, string narration, DateTime dt)
    {
        try
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblFolding(FoldingID, Name,Quantity,Narration,DateTime)VALUES(@id, @name, @qty, @narration,@dt)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", qty);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@narration", narration);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dt);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return new TClass { Result = 1 };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new TClass { Result = o, Error = ex };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return structured information, You can alter some parameter and so on. But preferebly You should catch exception at place where You are able to process it.

```
try
{
    clsStockManagement.updateStock(
        int.Parse(TransactionID.Text),
        int.Parse(projectID.Text),
        int.Parse(cbItem.SelectedValue.ToString()),
        int.Parse(tbQty.Text),
        DateTimee.Value);

    MessageBox.Show("Process Successful", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Process UnSuccessful, error:" + ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```